# PDO - Invalid syntax for UPDATE query

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am getting the error, `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= time + '1' WHERE username = 'admin-test'' at line 1` when I attempt to preform the following query:

```
try
{
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE alltimehighscores time = time + :time
        WHERE username = :username");
    $arr = array(
        ':username' => $username,
        ':time' => $time
        );
    $sth->execute($arr);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

The `$time` and `$username` values are assigned earlier on from `$_GET`. `$dbh` is also assigned above, which is working fine as there is another query above which executes fine.

Looking at the error message I can see that `time` isn't being changed into the current database value so I am assuming that there must be a different way of doing this when using PDO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a SET

```
UPDATE alltimehighscores SET time = time + :time WHERE username = :username
```

Answer (score 1):

`SET` is missing:

```
UPDATE alltimehighscores SET `time` = `time` + :time
WHERE username = :username
```